# What is the difference between "over a year since..." and "over a year on since..."?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Could you tell what the difference is between *over a year since* and *over a year on since*? For example:

> **Over a year since** the first outbreak of the disease, we have to take stoke of what we've learned about it.
>
> **Over a year on since** the first outbreak of the disease, we have to take stoke of what we've learned about it.

Comment: **Over a year on since** sounds wrong to this US English speaker.  Did you find this sentence somewhere, or is it one you wrote yourself?  (Also, "take stoke" should be **take stock**.)

Comment: I've actually heard it.

Comment: "Over a year on *since* ..." doesn't sound right to me. Perhaps you're thinking of "Over a year on, we have to take ..." which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Cigien: Could you tell me what the "on" in "over a year on" mean?

Comment: Minor point: you should say `@username` when you want to ping another user in chat, otherwise they don't get notified. I only saw this because I looked at the post again. To answer your question, "a year on" just means "a year later". If you've heard the phrase "later on", it's essentially the same thing.